# SQLite error after COTURN installation on Ubuntu Server 16.04.1

Tags: software-installation, sqlite

I'm Installing COTURN on Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 according instructions from [here](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/TURN-server-installation-guide.html).
All steps done well but when trying to run `turnserver` this error happens:

```
Error retrieving SQLite DB information: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

I have googled for above error and mostly it occurs in version conflict of `SQLite`. But I've done steps exactly according to installation instructions and have no idea how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone encounters same problem:

1) Install SQLite3:

```
>> sudo apt-get update
>> sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

2) In [install documentation](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/TURN-server-installation-guide.html) there is an error when defining database file in  `etc/turnserver.conf`:

```
userdb=/etc/turnuserdb.conf
```

should be changed to:

```
userdb=/var/lib/turn/turndb
```

**PS:**

Here are important parts of `turnuserdb.conf` in case you need:

```
# you can listen ports 80 and 443 instead of 3478/5349
listening-port=3478
alt-listening-port=0

tls-listening-port=5349
alt-tls-listening-port=0

listening-ip=YourPublicIPv4
relay-ip=YourPublicIPv4
external-ip=YourPublicIPv4

# realm=yourdomain.com
# server-name=yourdomain.com

# lt-cred-mech
# userdb=/etc/turnuserdb.conf

oauth
user=youruser:yourpassword

# use real-valid certificate/privatekey files
# cert=/etc/ssl/certificate.pem
# pkey=/etc/ssl/private.key

no-stdout-log
```

Consider using your `YourPublicIPv4` (x.x.x.x) and `youruser:yourpassword`.

Comment: Thanks that's useful.  How did you configure the username and password in the db? Could you maybe share your `turnserver.conf` file as a gist?

Comment: @Lukasz: I have updated answer.

Comment: I am getting
`CONFIG ERROR: Empty cli-password, and so telnet cli interface is disabled!
Please set a non empty cli-password!
bind: Cannot assign requested address
Cannot bind local socket to addr: Cannot assign requested address`

Can you please help me with that

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the latest source from [Github](https://github.com/coturn/coturn/wiki/Downloads).
2. Extract the file:

   `tar -xvfz turnserver-<...>.tar.gz`
3. Use the schema turndb/schema.sql to create a new database:

   `sqlite3 <new_file_name> < turndb/schema.sql`
4. Replace the new database with the original database in `/var/lib/turn/`

Also, using Ubuntu18 might cause problems. Use Ubuntu16 instead.